# Write the prettiest bytebeat composition

Tags: popularity-contest, c, music

[Bytebeat](http://canonical.org/~kragen/bytebeat/) is a style of music one can compose by writing a simple C program that's output is piped to `aplay` or `/dev/dsp`.

```
main(t){for(;;t++)putchar(((t<<1)^((t<<1)+(t>>7)&t>>12))|t>>(4-(1^7&(t>>19)))|t>>7);}
```

There is a good deal of information on the [bytebeat site](http://canonical.org/~kragen/bytebeat/), a [javascript implementation](http://wurstcaptures.untergrund.net/music/), and more demos and example compositions in [this thread](http://www.metafilter.com/111959/Todays-formulaic-music).

Very simple rules : Try to write a pretty sounding composition.  Most up votes wins since that's obviously subjective, although not that subjective considering the usual results.

Comment: [Useful blog article](http://countercomplex.blogspot.com/2011/10/some-deep-analysis-of-one-line-music.html)

Comment: Are you holding this to strict bytebeat (i.e. no buffers)?

Comment: Why is it restricted to C?

Comment: There isn't afaik any intrinsic reason to restrict using buffers or other languages, but usually bytebeat means that particular C loop with the output defined by a formula.  I voted up Joey Adams answer even thought `rand()` is non-standard.

Comment: While I like this idea, the FAQ calls for an objective winning criteria (it's too easy to get trapped in calculations or ASCII art). Can we look for something better defined than "pretty"?

Comment: Also it should be tagged with one of [code-golf], [code-challenge], [king-of-the-hill], etc. I assume that you want [code-challenge] for this one.

Comment: Any suggestions?  I donno much music theory, but melodic or harmonic might be over specified.  How about "Write a bytebeat composition that doesn't sound too computer generated", not necessarily more objective, but specificity often yields objectivity in practice.  I doubt you want the up votes by March 1st precedent

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.livescience.com/33050-what-makes-music-enjoyable.html) maybe? It states that there is a correlation between  our enjoyment of music and how much it can be compressed. I doubt it is reliable in any way but it is an objective winning criteria

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Signed 16-bit little endian, 8000Hz mono (`--format=S16_LE`))

### Music

**Much** better than before! (although it's quite long)

`main(t){for(;;t++)putchar(((7&(((t>>17)+1)>>2)+((t>>10)&1+2*(t>>18&1))*(("23468643"[7&t>>12]-48)+(3&t>>11))+((3&t>>17)>0)*(3&t>>9)*!(1&t>>10)*(((2+t>>10&3)^(2+t>>11&3))))*t*"@06+"[3&t>>15]/32));}`

(You can listen this [at here](http://snd.sc/zFYrxo))

I wrote this, but even I don't know how some part works, like `>0` and (especially) the first `7&`.

Change for loop to `for(;!(t>>22);t++)`... to listen it 'once'. I don't know whether it "loops" exactly the same way, however.

### Melody (base of above music)

I love this melody I made (C-G-A-F ftw), but it's too 'plain'...

`main(t){for(;;t++)putchar(((t>>10)&1)*(t*("23468643"[7&t>>12]-48)+t*(3&t>>11))*"@06+"[3&t>>15]/32);}`

### Simple music (which I made before)

`main(t){for(;;t++)putchar(t*(3&t>>11)+(t&t>>11)*4*!((t>>11)%3));}`

Comment: If you click the above bytebeat link, you'll see a sox command line to convert it to a .wav file, and an odd compressor command line.

Comment: +1 Amazing!  A few bits (e.g. 1:30 - 1:40) sound kind of "stuttering", but then again, much of the very charm of bytebeat is in these odd and unconventional rhythms and melodies, and the overall effect is excellent.  (Ps. I accidentally played this at 8 bits per sample, and I sounds surprisingly good that way too.  Sort of like playing a 45 rpm vinyl at 33.3 rpm.)

Answer (score 3):

The [ruler function](http://oeis.org/A001511) in C minor:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

#define step(freq, n) ((freq) * pow(2, (n) / 12.0))
#define note(n)       step(440, n)
#define MIDDLE_C      note(-9)

int count_zeros(unsigned int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (; (n & 1) == 0; n >>= 1)
        count++;
    return count;
}

int minor_note(int note)
{
    int octave = note / 7;
    int scale[] = {0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10};

    note %= 7;
    if (note < 0) {
        note += 7;
        octave--;
    }

    return scale[note] + octave*12;
}

int main(void) {
    double t = 0.0;
    double freq = MIDDLE_C * 2;
    double step = PI * 2 / 8192;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1;; t += step, i++) {
        if (i == 1024) {
            i = 0;
            n++;
            freq = step(MIDDLE_C, minor_note(count_zeros(n)));
        }

        putchar(sin(t * freq) * 50.0 + 128.0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice melody, but to be a "composition" this IMO needs something more...

Answer (score 3):

```
main(t){for(;;t+=(t%6)?1:2)putchar((((t<<t^(t>>8))|(t<<7))*((t<<t&(t>>12))|(t<<10))));}
```

Comment: Very classic bytebeat, if that's not an oxymoron.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Emphasising "beat" over "byte":

```
#include<math.h>

double s(double,double);double r(double,double);double d(double);double f(double);

char bytebeat(int t){return (d(f(t/4000.)/3) + 1) * 63;}
double f(double t){
  double sn=s(1./2,t-1); sn*=(sn*sn);
  return 3*s(1./4,1/s(1,t))+3*s(4,1/sn)/2+s(4,1/(sn*sn*sn*sn*sn))/4
       +2*s(55+18.3*r(1./2,t),t)+s(110+s(5,t)/4000,t)*s(1,t)+s(220+110*r(1,t)+55*r(3,t),t)/5
       +s(880+440*r(1./2,t)-220*r(1,t)+110*r(2,t)+s(5,t)/4000,t)
       *(2+s(1760+438*r(3./2,t)-1234*r(2,t)+423*r(5,t),t))/9
       +s(s(1,t)+s(1./2,t)+s(1./4,t)+s(1./8,t),t)*s(s(1,t)+s(1./2,t)+s(1./4,t)+s(1./8,t)+1,t)
       +r(264+11*r(1./20,t),t)*s(1./20,t);
}
double s(double f,double t){return d(sin(f*3.14159265*(t+999)));}
double r(double f,double t){return s(f,t)<0;}
double d(double a){return tanh(a+a*a/4);}

main(t){for(;;++t)putchar(bytebeat(t));}
```

To be used at 8 kHz, uint8 mono. Sounds best over decently bass-capable loudspeakers.

Answer (score 2):

```
main(){for(;;)putchar(rand());}
```

Sounds like the ocean ;-)

Comment: More like a really busy railway crossing to me. :)

Comment: Protip: if it sounds like a continuous tone, your RNG is broke.

Comment: easier way: `$ cat /dev/urandom | aplay`

Comment: @B1KMusic much more simple: `aplay /dev/urandom`

Answer (score 0):

Combined melody and harmony:

```
r=3,
r=3,
m=(t*(t>>12|t>>13|t>>14|t>>15|t>>16|t>>17|t>>18))&63,

h= ((t&t>>7&t>>6)|t*5&t>>8-c^t*6&t>>9-c|t*7&t>>12-c^t*9&t>>11-c^t*11&t>>22^t*19&t>>20^t*14&t>>20|t*23&t>>15-c|t*12&t>>9|t*30&t>>30|t>>5|t>>4)-31, m|h
```